# Laravel Eloquent load relationship inside pivot relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-query-builder

I'm searching to load a relation inside a pivot table with "->with()".

Table structure: Are 5 tables and Laravel Eloquent models

**user** (id)
**team** (id)
**role** (id)
**team_user** (id, team_id, user_id)
**team_user_role** (id, team_user_id, role_id)

```
class User extends Model {
    function teams(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class)
            ->using(TeamUser::class);
    }
}

class Team extends Model {
    function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
            ->using(TeamUser::class);
    }
}

class TeamUser extends Pivot {
    function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)
            ->using(TeamUserRole::class);
    }
}

class Role extends Model {}
class TeamUserRole extends Pivot {}
```

Ok, I can do that and this works perfectly, the "->with()" function load roles relationship from TeamUser...

```
TeamUser::with('roles')->first()->roles // return list of Role::class
```

...but I need load this "roles" relationship from User::class "User->teams->roles":

```
User::with('teams')
    ->with('teams.pivot.roles') // Something like this
    ->first()->teams->pivot->roles; // Expected a list of Role::class
```

This way a got a RelationNotFoundException, that's make sense because 'pivot' is not a relationship...

So, in this scenery, how can I access the list of roles from user using QueryBuilder?

Thanks.

**[Edit]**

I tried:

```
User::with('teams.roles') // got a RelationNotFoundException
```

Comment: Does `User::with('teams.roles')` work?

Comment: I tried that and got the same RelationNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `withPivot()` method in your model  :

```
class Role extends Model {
    public function 
}
```

then :

```
User::with('teams')
    ->with('teams.roles') // Something like this
    ->first()->teams->pivot->{attributes};
```

If you really want to access the Role pivot as an eloquent model :

```
class User extends Model {
    function teams(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class)
            ->using(TeamUser::class);
    }

     function roles(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Role::class, Team::class);
    }


}
```

```
User::with('roles')->get();
```

see the docs for more informations :

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

If you need a more deep relation in your case, you should considerate this package :

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Comment: Ok, thank you for the detailed answer... I had tried withPivot(), but I hasn't success with that, I think I forgot something. But I'm curious where you sugest me to use withPivot(), I can't see in your example.

About the hasManyThrough(), I think this is really what I need, I will try that, thank you again.

Comment: I took a look at hasManyThrough(), but this is not what I need, hasManyThrough() doenst use pivot table, it is only a shortcut to relations. In my case I have "TeamUserRole" that "belongsTo" pivot table "TeamUser" and a "Role". In other words I have a pivot table(TeamUserRole) that has relation with another pivot table (TeamUser).

Comment: hasManyDeep() was exactly what I needed! thank you again.